# Why is `pk=None` in the DRF documentation of `detail_route`? Does it have to default to None?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions the `detail_route` example given is:

```
@detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsAdminOrIsSelf])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
```

`pk=None` is the third parameter. This route can be accessed when going to the URL `users/{pk}/change-password/$`. My question is, isn't `pk` always provided? Why is the default value `None`? Shouldn't it just be:

```
@detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsAdminOrIsSelf])
    def set_password(self, request, pk):
```

? From my understanding the only way a user can access this route is by entering the `pk` value in the url `users/{pk}/change-password/$` (shouldn't default values be used when the value might Not be given - and if it isn't, default to `None`)?

Comment: I'm 90% sure this is a documentation issue, stemming from changes over two years ago, and I'd recommend follow up on GitHub with a ticket about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly a matter of style. Since Django url resolution method is to pass keywords arguments to views whenever named groups is used in regex and given that DRF uses named groups then we tend to use the keyword "style" notation.

Comment: Right, so since Django passes keyword arguments to views when named groups is used, shouldn't `pk` be needed since DRF uses named groups? Why is it optional?

Comment: the "=None" is simply here to mark the argument as a keyword one. Only the positional arguments can be required. Simple read the "=None" as a tag to make the argument a keyword one.

Comment: This is a little bit counter-intuitive since someone who is still learning Django and DRF would expect the possibility of the pk being None in some cases. And that leads to doubts and having these kinds of questions. Not a big issue though.